# ReactJs calling NodeJs api failed with error- 'keycloak-token' of undefined?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, keycloak

I have nodejs api integrated with Keycloak and here is the keycloak configuration

```
{
  "realm": "realm",
  "auth-server-url": "<IP-ADDRESS>/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "client-id",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "public-client": true,
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0,
  "policy-enforcer": {}
}
```

and here how secure it

```
//Secure api with Keycloak
const keycloak = require('./config/keycloak-config.js').initKeycloak();
app.use(keycloak.middleware());
app.use("/api/posts",keycloak.protect(), posts);
```

Now tested with it POSTMAN and in header passed `'Authorization: Bearer Token'`  and its working totally fine.

Now come to the issue when trying to access same api with reactjs its failing

```
function getAll(pageNo, limit){
    return httpClient({
        url: `api/posts?page=${pageNo}&limit=${limit}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.getItem('authentication'),
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
    });
}
```

Its failed with the below error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'keycloak-token' of undefined

Comment: Did you add `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` for CORS?

Comment: @StackedQ See its already there in reactjs code.

Comment: It should be on express side, not in frontend

Comment: there i am using `app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
`

Answer (score 1):

This issue i was getting because nodejs `cors` was added after keycloak intialization

```
const keycloak = require('./config/keycloak-config.js').initKeycloak();
app.use(keycloak.middleware()); 
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
```

Which should be

```
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
const keycloak = require('./config/keycloak-config.js').initKeycloak();
app.use(keycloak.middleware());
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue I was getting because nodejs cors was added after keycloak initialization,

`app.use(keycloak.middleware())` after

```
 app.use(cors())
```